# Reorder Javascript loading in theme?

Tags: javascript

Some modules insert JavaScript at top of list. I put my $sctipts variable at the bottom of html.tpl.php file just before the closing of body tag.
Due to this, some scripts do not work as they get called before jquery or drupal.js . 
Please provide steps to reorder list of js.
I tried this code in my template.php but with no effect:

```
function MYTHEME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  $javascript['sites/all/modules/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.min.js']['group'] = 500;
  $javascript['sites/all/modules/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.min.js']['weight'] = 500;
}
```

**Solved. I did this**: enabled AdvAgg Modifier, Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation. Then I visited settings page /admin/config/development/performance/advagg/mod where I checked options: Enable preprocess on all JS,  Move all inline scripts to the bottom of the execution order, Move all browser conditional JavaScript to the bottom of the group, Move JS to the footer - All. 
And now i have all JS in the bottom (as google recommends), without need to chane html.tpl.php

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/ should be able to do what you're wanting to do.

Comment: thank you! it helped me to optimize my site without any errors. So i did this: enabled AdvAgg Modifier, Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation. Then I visited settings page /admin/config/development/performance/advagg/mod where I checked options: Enable preprocess on all JS, Remove unused JavaScript if possible,  Move all inline scripts to the bottom of the execution order,  Move all browser conditional JavaScript to the bottom of the group, Move JS to the footer - All. And now i have all JS in the bottom (as google recommends), without need to chane html.tpl.php. GREAT!

Comment: @tlito It'd be great if you could write that comment up as an answer, maybe help some people with the same problem in the future :)

Comment: @tlito - please help others out by posting your solution as an **answer**, as Clive suggested. Otherwise this post will remain as unanswered forever.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I did this: enabled AdvAgg Modifier, Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation. Then I visited settings page

/admin/config/development/performance/advagg/mod

where I checked options:

- Enable preprocess on all JS,
- Move all inline scripts to the bottom    of the execution order,
- Move all browser conditional JavaScript to    the bottom of the    group,
- Move JS to the footer - All.

And now i have all JS in the bottom (as google recommends), without need to chane html.tpl.php